# method or function to be blocked for a set about of time, Java, Android

Tags: java, android, timer, singleton, thread-sleep

what is a good and efficient way to make a method that will be callable once, and during a time period like 2 minutes, it is blocked from being called any more during the 2 minute interval.  only after the two minutes is over then it can be called again.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you speak about an external (over an API) or about an internal (an object calls a method) call?

Comment: an internal method to the class

Comment: you know what, I wrote the answer for you and 5 minutes later I have to use it in my code now :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep and update a `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a static variable, and check if current `System.currentTimeMillis()` is two minutes bigger than stored `System.currentTimeMillis()`. if so; go on, do whatever you want to do, if not; you can just simply return, or throw an exception to catch it later, it is your call.

Comment: You need to *update* System.currentTimeMillis() that you are saving in the static variable.